# Chat between two people sharing byobu screen

Tags: byobu

It is very convenient to use byobu for sharing terminal screen.

Is there a convenient way to have a chat window inside byobu?

Comment: You can always type `echo "Hi There! You can chat using the echo command."` It will show up twice, once as a command and once below it as an "echo".

Comment: Ther is a write command in terminal, but I believe you have to enable it , not sure. http://linux.die.net/man/1/write

Comment: @user68186 not as convenient as real chat, as you both control the keyboard at the same time

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely!  This we do this all the time.  There's a couple of little, lightweight options:

1. On a command line, just start with the shell comment character, "#", like: `# hey, dustin here, what are you doing with that file?`
2. Open up a text editor like [vi(1)](http://manpg.es/vi) or [emacs(1)](http://manpg.es/emacs) and start typing
3. Use the [wall(1)](http://manpg.es/wall) command to talk to all windows everywhere

Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).

Comment: Thanks. This is still not as convenient as chat. For example, while I'm typing `# hey dustin,` Dustin might want to type something else, and I'm taking the keyboard. If byobu itself had a "chat" window and recognize different keystroke from different sessions - that would be nicer (and if more than two people involved, would save the hassle of writing your name). Thanks!

Comment: Hash-chat is like radio communicationn, where you need to say "Over" at the end of your message. I'm looking for a phone ;-).